# JSON Parse objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, parsing, touchjson

I´ve got the next json code:

```
{

"person_1":{
      "name" :"person",
      "pictures":[ 
                  {"images":{
                             "picture_1": "url1",
                             "picture_2": "url1",
                            }
                  }
               ],
}
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to get the element "picture_1"?
I am using touchJson for objective c.

Best Regards

Comment: Please read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend using [yajl](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc) as I found it very convenient for my work.

```
NSBundle * personBundle = [[yourstring yajl_JSON] valueForKey:@"person_1"];
NSArray * picturArray = [personBundle valueForKey:"pictures"];
NSBundle * imagesBundle = [picturArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * myUrl = [imagesBundle valueForKey:"picture_1"];
```

This should pretty much do it.

Comment: I think you meant NSDictionary*, not NSBundle*

Comment: Using valueForKeyPath is cleaner and easier in this case.

Comment: @Fiorze Lafeer @nonamelive - I'm not an Objectie-C expert (not even close) so I showed it in the way I implement it, so first, thank for the comment, second, if you don't mind, please elaborate and third, I find it is hard to start with something new only with reading documentation and that an example helps many times, and since no one answered - I took the shot. Finally, if you have a better approach I would be **very very happy** to see your answers as well and learn from it.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer.. Its´s work!!! but I´ve to create another NSDictionary after the array like this:

Comment: NSDictionary *item_1 = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"person_1"];
    NSArray *node_images =[item_1 objectForKey:@"pictures"];
    NSDictionary *files = [[node_images objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"images"]; NSString * stri = [files objectForKey:@"picture_1"];
    
 
    NSString * stri = [files objectForKey:@"preview"];